# Getting the page of a Facebook User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to find the pages a Facebook user has created?
I don't want to use the manage_pages permission since I don't want to modify them,
but just to create a link to those pages.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not.

Also, the `manage_pages` permission doesn't do that. It will return you the pages the user administers (i.e. is an admin of), not the ones he created.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do this in a single call.

Using a call like: $pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');

Will get you a list of all 'accounts' that the active token/user has access to - but wont show which ones they created themselves.

To my knowledge the 'creator' isn't a value returned anywhere in the open graph for a page - if you check the reference for pages in general:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

You'll see only references to users and admins.